# Python FTPLib Won't Upload Complete File

Tags: python, ftplib

I am using the following code to upload a SQLITE3 Database file. For some reason, the script does not completely upload the file (the uploaded filesize is less than the original)

```
FTP = ftplib.FTP('HOST','USERNAME','PASSWORD')
FTP.cwd('/public_html/')
FILE = 'Database.db';
FTP.storbinary("STOR " + FILE, open(FILE, 'r'))                               
FTP.quit()
```

When I go to open the uploaded file in SQLite Browser, it says it is an invalid file.
What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: How large is the file? Does it work when you open the file with `'rb'` instead of `'r'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) call, you need to specify that the file is a binary file, like so:

```
FTP.storbinary("STOR " + FILE, open(FILE, 'rb'))
```

Comment: This fixed it. Is 'b' only for Windows or can it work in Unix?

Comment: In this use case, using Python2, `b` is safe for all platforms and required on Windows. Using Python3, `b` is required on all platforms.